# RealmList.addAll() throws Primary key value already exists

Tags: android, realm

I'm having an issue when I try to call `addAll()` on `RealmList<Tile>` with `accounts` which are already stored in realm file.

`realmList.addAll(tiles)` is called based on a response from an API call which may return `Tiles` containing one ore more `accounts` already stored in realm. The object return by the API looks like the one below:

```
public class ActivityStreamData extends RealmObject {

        @PrimaryKey
        private long id = DB_ID;
        public String timestamp;
        public RealmList<Tile> activity = new RealmList<>();
        public MessageListMeta metadata = new MessageListMeta();
    }

public class Tile extends RealmObject {

    public String type;
    public RealmList<Account> accounts;
    public Account account;

}

public class Account extends RealmObject {

    @PrimaryKey
    public long id;
    public String timestamp;
    public String name;
    public String email;

}
```

The call fails when trying to add `tiles` to the  `activityStream.activity` list when fetching more.

Any way to force `addAll` to act as a `createOrUpdate` call

Comment: Try `realmList.addAll(realm.copyToRealmOrUpdate(tiles))`?